# Groovy GPars Script

Tags: groovy

```
GParsPool.withPool(numberPool) {

            connection.withBatch(10000) { stmt ->
                inputFile.eachParallel { data ->

                    //GParsPool.withPool() {
                        stmt.addBatch("DELETE FROM user WHERE number = ${data.toLong()} ")
                        println "IN"
                    //}
                }

                println "OUT"
                Long startTimee = System.currentTimeMillis()

                stmt.executeBatch()
                println "deleted Batch"

                Long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                println "Time taken for each batch: " + ((endTime - startTimee) / 1000)

            }
        }
```

The Above code is used to delete data from database. I First get the data from file and then match the each file data with database data and perform the delete query. But I have 5533179 records its take to much time. Even I have used the gpars but i get the same performance issue that is given by without using gpars. I have set the `numberPool=5` but same issue. Even I increase the `numberPool` again same issue

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the SQL `in` operator? thus you can process the data much faster.

UPDATE:

from the top of my head:

```
GParsPool.withPool(numberPool) {
    Map buffPerThread = [:].withDefaults{ [] }

    inputFile.eachParallel { data ->
      def buff = buffPerThread[ Thread.currentThread().id ]
      buff << data.toLong()
      if( 1000 == buff.size() ){
        sql.execute 'DELETE FROM user WHERE number in (?)', [ buff ]
        buff.clear()
      }
    }
 }
```

I wouldn't use `conn.withBatch` here, as the `in` statement give the desired batching already

Comment: ok i will use. but also tell me whats the performance issue in above code. Is I have not used the gpars correctly with batch statement?

Comment: how big your `inputFile` is? how many ids it usually contains?

Comment: 5533179 records in inputFile.

Comment: injecteer the buff.size() and buff.clear() give the error cannot resolve symbol. he output is bellow when i run the program                   Total records in File: 53550 
Initial DB Count: 5533179 
Deleted Records Count: 0 
Final DB Count: 5533179 
Time taken: 7.666 sec

Comment: what symbol? post your stacktrace

Comment: symbol mean buff.size() and buff.clear().  even i run your code its not delete the data. when i direct write the argument of inputfile in the query argument not the buff then its delete the data but takes 2234.56 sec as normally take.

Comment: post your stacktrace!